# Relating to combustion

Tags: combustion

Can i make a gel/liquid/any kind of solution which supports combustion but at the same time protect the surface from getting burnt? I wanted to light a log on fire using some kind of fuel which allows the gel/liquid/solution/fuel to burn but protect the actual log from undergoing charring